# Codeigniter - Get current route

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm looking for help to know which route my Codeigniter application goes through.

In my application folder in config/routes.php i got some database generated routes, could look like this:

```
$route["user/:any"] = "user/profile/$1";
$route["administration/:any"] = "admin/module/$1";
```

If i for example to go domain.net/user/MYUSERNAME, then i want to know that i get through the route "user/:any".
Is it possible to know which route it follows?

Comment: I think that will be hard to do maybe you want to fetch class or know method that is beeing used? `$this->router->fetch_class();` and `$this->router->fetch_method();`. Or perhaps you can build your routes by function (created by you) with simple `$this->uri->segment(n);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used @Ochi's answer to come up with this.

```
$routes = array_reverse($this->router->routes); // All routes as specified in config/routes.php, reserved because Codeigniter matched route from last element in array to first.
foreach ($routes as $key => $val) {
$route = $key; // Current route being checked.

    // Convert wildcards to RegEx
    $key = str_replace(array(':any', ':num'), array('[^/]+', '[0-9]+'), $key);

    // Does the RegEx match?
    if (preg_match('#^'.$key.'$#', $this->uri->uri_string(), $matches)) break;
}

if ( ! $route) $route = $routes['default_route']; // If the route is blank, it can only be mathcing the default route.

echo $route; // We found our route
```

Answer (score 8):

One way to know the route could be using this:

`$this->uri->segment(1);`

This would give you **'user'** for this url:

**domain.net/user/MYUSERNAME**

By this way you can easily identify the route through which you have been through.

Comment: Wanted user/:any. This solution cant help that.

Answer (score 2):

For CodeIgniter 4:

```php
var_dump(service('router')->getMatchedRoute());
```

It will return something like this:

```
[
    "{locale}/(.*)",
    "\App\Controllers\Home_controller::any/home"
];
```

Answer (score 1):

looking at the latest version it's not possible without using custom router as [ROUTEKEY is used and overwritten](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Router.php#L394) trying to parse the route

if you would like to create and use custom class it's only a matter of saving original `$key` to another variable and setting it as a class property for later use when you have a match (line 414 before "return" - you can get that key later as e.g. `$this->fetch_current_route_key()`) - other thing to remember is that this kind of code modification is easy to break if original class will change (update) so keep that in mind

Comment: I made a script which your answer helped me doing. I matched the current URI with the all the routes.