# codeigniter 3 URI routing - geting right hand side from given url

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I need to simulate routing in Codeigniter 3, so my question is how to get the right-hand side from any URL programmatically?

for example, some routes that I have:

```
$route["blog"] = "Main/blog/en";
$route["blog/(:any)"] = "Main/blog/en/$1";
$route["novosti"] = "Main/blog/sr";
$route["novosti/(:any)"] = "Main/blog/sr/$1";
$route["contact"] = "Main/contact/en";
$route["kontakt"] = "Main/contact/sr";
```

Now I need a function that can return right-hand side for a given URL part something like this:

```
echo $this->route->item("novosti/petar")
```

should print then Main/blog/sr/$1 or Main/blog/sr/petar

Is there such a function in Codeigniter, because I can't find it in documentation?

**UPDATE:**
I am looking throughout system/router class and I see that protected function _parse_routes is doing something similar so if there is no function that can give me what I need I will create one based on this one.

Comment: Hey @DejanDozet, May be this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24844517/codeigniter-get-current-route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codeigniter is simple, too simple... And because it is not obvious for me where that function is (if exists at all) I've just adopted _parse_routes to parse URL (slug) into the right-hand side from which I can find the corresponding file much easier.

Here it is (if someone gets in the same situation I was).

```
  function parseRoute($uri) {

    // Get HTTP verb
    $http_verb = isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) ? strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) : 'cli';

    // Loop through the route array looking for wildcards
    foreach ($this->router->routes as $key => $val) {
      // Check if route format is using HTTP verbs
      if (is_array($val)) {
        $val = array_change_key_case($val, CASE_LOWER);
        if (isset($val[$http_verb])) {
          $val = $val[$http_verb];
        } else {
          continue;
        }
      }

      // Convert wildcards to RegEx
      $key = str_replace(array(':any', ':num'), array('[^/]+', '[0-9]+'), $key);

      // Does the RegEx match?
      if (preg_match('#^' . $key . '$#', $uri, $matches)) {
        // Are we using callbacks to process back-references?
        if (!is_string($val) && is_callable($val)) {
          // Remove the original string from the matches array.
          array_shift($matches);

          // Execute the callback using the values in matches as its parameters.
          $val = call_user_func_array($val, $matches);
        }
        // Are we using the default routing method for back-references?
        elseif (strpos($val, '$') !== FALSE && strpos($key, '(') !== FALSE) {
          $val = preg_replace('#^' . $key . '$#', $val, $uri);
        }

        return $val;
      }
    }

    // If we got this far it means we didn't encounter a
    // matching route so we'll set the site default route
    return null;
  }
```

Now, this:

```
echo parseRoute("novosti/petar")
```

will produce:

```
Main/blog/sr/petar
```

AKA: Controler class / function inside that controller / language param / blog article

Answer (score 0):

use this

`$this->router->routes['blog']`

you will get

`Main/blog/en`

Comment: Just simple as that? Will $this->router->routes['blog/petar'] work as well?

Comment: @DejanDozet you can use `$this->router->routes['blog/(:any)']` to retrieve that which would return `Main/blog/en/$1`

Comment: @DejanDozet you can also use `uri_string();` to get the whole `URL` string

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the required info using the below code.

```
$this->router->routes['novosti/(:any)'];
```